# Using canActivate Angular with AngularFirebase2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've read and tried a trillion suggestions already.

Some 2 years ago, I did Auth Guard in Angular using AngularFire2 like this:

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) =>  {
      if(auth == null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.allowed = false;
      } else {
        this.allowed = true;
      }
    })
    return this.allowed;
  }
```

Today, I'm trying to replicate same auth guard, using today's javascript

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.2
Node: 11.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.2
@angular/cli                      7.3.2
@angular/fire                     5.1.1
@angular/pwa                      0.12.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.2
@schematics/angular               7.3.2
@schematics/update                0.13.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

I understand a few things have changed with `rxjs`, so something like this

`this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) =>  {`

now becomes

`this.af.authState.pipe(map(auth) => {`

Except doing the above causes the browser tab to hang on me.

I've seen at least 15 different questions on how to do route guarding using AngularFirebase, and they all take a different approach.

I know things will change (very likely) in the coming months how to do this, but as at 2019, Feb 18, how do you do route guarding using AngularFire2?

**Edit**

Here's where it gets interesting/weird. I tried @sergey-mell answer below.

Here's how I'm applying the `authGuard` within the routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'new', component: NewcustomerComponent },
      { path: ':customer_id', component: CustomerdetailComponent }
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

What happens is, if not logged in, and I visit directly in the browser, `localhost:4200/`, the browser hangs.

In console, Chrome informs me to visit the URL below

https://crbug.com/882238

I follow the link, and I'm told I don't have permission to view the bug. The bug that is bugging me. Okay.

[image]

So is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface:

1. If to look through the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) Guard can return an Observable which resolves into `boolean`.
2. [AngularFire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) show that we can use `AngularFireAuth.user` observable to check user auth state.

So, as to me, your guard should look as follows:

```
@Injectable()
class LetMeInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private routes: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afAuth.user.pipe(
      map(user => {
         if (!user) {
             this.router.navigate(['/login']);
         }
         return !!user;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Using the above, although I have `import 'rxjs/operators/map;` it complains: `Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?`

Comment: No, you should use `map`. Just add `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';` at the top of the file

Comment: So I've updated the question. in summary, the above approach hangs my browser.

Comment: I think that the browser hangs because you don't have `/login` route in your list. In this case Angular redirects you to main page and your guard executes more and more times

Comment: Thank you. Silly oversight on my part. Have added a catchall notfound path at the end of the routes. Really appreciates. Hopefully, the above solution will continue working for the rest of the month, until it changes to something totally bizarre. ;)

Comment: I am glad to help